# QML Audio crashing application

Tags: qt, audio, qml, qt5, qtquick2

My QML app worked without problems under Qt 5.1.
Now I use Qt 5.2 and creating a QML `Audio` element like this:

```
Audio {
    id: myAudio
    source: "qrc:///sounds/MySound.wav"
}
```

leads to the application crashing before even the main window is shown.
I tried loading the audio from a file and from a resource with no difference.

But it gets even worse (stranger, at least):
The element creation works in the main qml file but not in a child item.
I can create an Audio element directly in the main qml file but if I put the same line
into another qml file which is use by the main qml file it doesn't work.

Has anybody encountered similar problems with `Audio` in Qt 5.2?

### Update

I can however start the application when I switch to debug build in QT Creator. In release configuration it still does not start. I use Win7 x64.

Comment: Where do you get the `Audio` element from? I can't find it in the online documentation or in the Qt source code for QML.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-audio.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the application in debug mode and check console output.
Try also this:

```
import QtMultimedia 5.0

SoundEffect {
    id: myAudio
    source: "qrc:///sounds/MySound.wav"
}
```

Comment: Debug helped my case and pointed to unsupported sample rates as one can see at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/media/+/c7369d04a4b94aca0462d0e0a38c243a80a945a9/opensles/libopensles/android_AudioPlayer.cpp